# how to integrate aspx page with php?

Tags: php, asp.net

I have aspx page for reading and writing word document.But my project is in PHP.
Now i want to integrate that aspx page with my PHP project.
I also want to know how to get textbox value of aspx page in PHP.

Comment: Why are you using aspx to write into Word? PHP does it fine `$this->oWord = new COM("word.Application")` should work.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET and PHP are completely two different platform. ASP.NET runs solely on IIS and on Windows, however PHP can be configured in IIS too, but that's a different story.

PHP is a different interpreted language where ASP.NET pages like aspx files are .NET compiled and rendered through ASP.NET.

Sorry to say that you cannot use or integrate you ASPX page to your PHP application and you will need to completely rewrite the ASPX page to PHP code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is only one but. If the server is Windows PHP could do the Word part just as well as ASPX. Since the code is already writed for the word part it should not be so long to rewrite.

Comment: @DavidLaberge agreed - wouldn't be difficult to rewrite